# Excel Code to autofill a Date if a Cell = YES

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula in my excel spreadsheet that will autofill C1 if B1=YES. I currently am using the following formula but it is not working. Any suggestions or fix for this is appreciated.

Tried this formula

```
=IF(B1="YES", IF(C1="",NOW(), C1), "")
```

Expected C1 cell to populate the current date

Comment: With that formula you have to allow circular references in the settings as it refers to itself.  This is not a robust method as the setting to allow circular references is not attached to the workbook/worksheet but for the whole local instance of excel.  As in if you do not want to allow it on certain workbooks but allow it here, you can't.  Also each user will need to go to their settings and allow it.  The best way to do this is using vba in a worksheet_change event which is worksheet specific and can also be written to be range specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using just functions if the function is in column C. You can use `=IF(B3="YES";TODAY();"")` in column C.

[image: 1]

Let me know if it's useful for you.